# Pre-loading a queue with simmer package

Tags: r, event-simulation

I would like to start a simmer simulation with a queue pre-loaded. I want to simulate a day on a mfg floor with several jobs already in the queue then during the day add more jobs to the queue. Here is my working code for starting the day with nothing in the queue.

How do I go about preloading the queue for the batch step with say 100 jobs?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(simmer)
library(simmer.bricks)

numMolds=480
mfgProcess <- simmer()

mfgfloor <-
  trajectory() %>%
    visit("CAD",10) %>% 
    batch(30) %>%
    visit("Printer",15)

mfgProcess %>%
  add_resource("CAD", 6) %>% 
  add_resource("Printer",1) %>% 
  add_generator("job", mfgfloor, function() {c(0, rep(0,numMolds-1), -1)}, mon=2)

mfgProcess %>% run(until=24*60)
```

Comment: Yes. But where are they pre-loading a queue? Am I missing it? The bank example also does not mirror what I am modeling ... the nurse/doctor/admin example would be a better one. Using the nurse/doctor/example my question would be, how would I start the simulation with all three doctors already seeing patients? I am trying to look at a day where there are jobs submitted from the day before that were processed but not printed.

Answer (score 0):

Just feed a data frame of arrivals (see `?add_dataframe`) at `t=0` with custom service times so that, say, at `t=1` your simulation starts in the conditions you want.